# Reset btn no quita validaciones CSS de Bootstrap4

Tags: html, bootstrap

Estoy siguiendo la guia de bootstrap de forms:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#server-side

En la cual, por parte de la respuesta del servidor, se le asigna la 
clase `is-invalid` al input para que aparezca incorrecto en caso de serlo.

El problema está en que el button reset del formulario, no limpia estas clases.

No se si es problema de los scripts o necesito hacer algo diferente además.

Les dejo un código ejemplo del error, el código es mucho más que esto, pero esto es lo básico a resolver:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationServer01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" id="validationServer01" placeholder="First name" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Ingrese un rut válido
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Limpiar">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El botón type reset sirve para resetear (restaurar) los valores de los campos del formulario, con las clases CSS no va a hacer nada. Puedes hacerlo con jQuery, ya que lo tienes cargado. Al botón reset le puedes poner un onclick:

```
<input type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" value="Limpiar" onclick="$('.is-invalid').removeClass('is-invalid');">
```